# R pass an Rscript command line with parameters to emacs ESS?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I would like to be able to debug an R script that is called with a list of parameters via emacs ESS. For example:

```
/specific/version/of/R/bin/Rscript \
    /my/dir/script.R \
    firstparam \
    /second/param/is/a/file.txt
```

Instead of my ESS session just calling R with no parameters, how can I pass these parameters above to the ESS session and debug the script line by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine script.R probably invokes the `commandArgs` functionality.  I don't think there's a way to 'write' to this once you've invoked R within , but once your script is open in emacs, and you have invoked R in the usual way, then step through the script as usual, but prior to any lines resembling `myvar <- commandArgs()[2]`, manually set myvar (or whatever variable the script is setting!) to firstparam, rather than allowing the commandArgs to attempt to read from the original command line.

Alternatively, you can invoke R to prompt you for optional arguments to R by using `C-u M-x R` and manually typing in firstparam etc, but the index of the arguments might not sync nicely between Rscript and your ESS's way of calling R, so experimentation may be needed.